# In Stata's esttab, omit line of model names

Tags: latex, regression, stata

I'm using Stata to produce regression tables with [esttab](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/esttab.html) and I want to include these tables in my Latex document.

I'm producing a regression table like this:

```
sysuse auto
eststo: regress price weight 
eststo: regress price weight mpg
eststo: regress price weight mpg headroom
eststo: regress price weight mpg length
esttab using "test.tex", nocons b(a2) replace stats(N r2, labels("Obs." "R$^2$")) nonumbers fragment booktabs
```

Then I use the following Latex code to produce my table:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\begin{small}
\begin{threeparttable}
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{Dep. var: } price in dollars} \\
\cline{2-5} 
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\
 \midrule
\input{test.tex}
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{threeparttable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item\textit{Note:} Here I'm putting many great comments about my regression setup. *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{small}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

All my problems would be solved if I could simply tell `esttab` not to produce this row of model names.

Any ideas?

---

*Edit:* The problem how to get rid of the line of model names was answered below by Eric HB. The follow-up problem of how to include Latex code starting with `\midrule` was answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385743/using-input-works-fails-on-similar-snippets-of-code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the option `nomtitles` will do this for you, so your code will be:

```
sysuse auto
eststo: regress price weight mpg
esttab using "test.tex", nocons b(a2) replace ///
   stats(N r2, labels("Obs." "R$^2$")) ///
   nonumbers fragment booktabs nomtitles
```

From `help esttab`:

> **nomtitles** suppresses printing of model titles.

Comment: That works, but now Latex is having a problem including the table. It throws an error: `\test.tex:1: Misplaced \noalign. [\midrule]
\test.tex:2: Missing } inserted. [f]
\test.tex:2: Missing } inserted. [f]`
...

Comment: It appears that the issue is the `\midrule` in test.tex and when I comment that out, the pdf compiles correctly. I will search around to see if there is a way to not start the `esttab` command's output with `\midrule`

Comment: See the edit in my question above. A follow-up question was able to solve it.